# Decentralizing functions in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

Am from Angular2 whereby i was used to services and injection of services hence reusing functions how do i achieve the same in vuejs

eg:

I would like to create only one function to set and retrieve localstorage data.
 so am doing it this way:

In my Login Component

```
  this.$axios.post('login')
      .then((res)=>{
        localstorage.setItem('access-token', res.data.access_token);
     })
```

Now in another component when sending a post request

```
export default{
 methods:{
  getvals(){
   localstorage.getItem('access-token') //do stuff after retrieve
   }
 }
}
```

Thats just one example, Imagine what could happen when setting multiple localstorage items when retrieving one can type the wrong key.

How can i centralize functionality eg: setting token(in angular2 would be services)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to share functionality between components in Vue, but I believe the most commonly used are either mixins or custom modules.

**Mixins**
Mixins are a way to define reusable functionality that can be injected into the component utilizing the mixin. Below is a simple example from the official [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html):

```
// define a mixin object
var myMixin = {
  created: function () {
    this.hello()
  },
  methods: {
    hello: function () {
      console.log('hello from mixin!')
    }
  }
}
// define a component that uses this mixin
var Component = Vue.extend({
  mixins: [myMixin]
})
var component = new Component() // => "hello from mixin!"
```

**Custom module**
If there are a lot of shared functionality with a logical grouping it might make sense to instead create a custom module, and import that where you need it (like how you inject a service in angular).

```
// localStorageHandler.js
const localStorageHandler = {
  setToken (token) {
    localStorage.setItem('access-token', token)
  },
  getToken () {
    localstorage.getItem('access-token')
  }
}

export default localStorageHandler
```

And then in your component:

```
// yourcomponent.vue
import localStorageHandler from 'localStorageHandler'
export default{
  methods:{
   getvals(){
      const token = localStorageHandler.getToken()
    }
  }
}
```

Modules are using the more modern syntax of JavaScript, which is not supported in all browsers, hence require you to preprocess your code. If you are using the [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) [webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) it should work out of the box.